# Why in AWS CLI is required to specify region when using pre-signed URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

When I use the command `aws s3 presign s3://my_bucket/my_image.png` without specifying region I get an URL which redirects me to

`<Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message>`

Later, if I use `aws s3 presign s3://my_bucket/my_image.png --region us-east-1` then it displays image correctly, but why is the `--region us-east-1` required in order to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because pre-signed S3 urls use `sig4` signatures and this requires region. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html):

> The signing key is **scoped to a specific Region** and service, and it never expires.

Also, from [CLI docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html):

> For sigv4 requests the **region needs** to be configured explicitly.